# Loading extension GLX : screen freezes

Tags: 12.10, xorg, desktop-environments

I installed Ubuntu Server edition 12.10 on a server (with 16 GB RAM and 500GB hard disk).
The installation was successful, after which I tried installing GUI using the below command
**`sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop`**  Now, the problem is I'm not able to start GUI from the terminal once I login. When I do startx, screen freezes and nothing works.
In the terminal, it displays loading extension GLX and stops.
I did **`grep EE /var/log/Xorg.0.log`**  which displayed the following lines.

**`[  247.145] (EE) open /dev/dri/card): No such file or directory`**
Why does this error occur. How can I solve this.

Answer (score 5):

It seems you have a driver on a wrong video adapter, run `lspci` and look for video adapter. My friend has the same problem - he installed a video driver for NVidia, but he had Intel video card. After `sudo apt-get purge nvidia-*` and reboot everything is fine.

Comment: I am getting this error but I'm on an NVidia Tegra TK1 (32bit ARM).  Any suggestions?  The machine is not using PCI slots.

Answer (score 0):

Running these fixed my issue:

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*
sudo apt-get install --reinstall xserver-xorg-video-intel libgl1-mesa-glx libgl1-mesa-dri xserver-xorg-core
sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg
```